# How do I access Azure AD claims in ASP.NET forms application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have a web forms app that we are in the process of moving into Azure. We want to authenticate against Azure AD.

Its very easy to turn on the authentication in the portal and restrict access to the app until authenticated. The issue is that I need to know then email address of the person who has been authenticated.

I was hoping to be able to intercept the callback URL (.auth/login/aad/callback) as it appears that this is where the information from AD is returning. However, I don't seem to be able to access this URL.

What I'm wondering is what Azure does with the extra claims that come back from AD and is there any way I can access this from within the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was terribly simple in the end. The magic I was unaware of is that the User object is populated behind the scenes, and that for my use case I could simply use:

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name